# If A and B are jointly independent of X, are A and B's complement jointly independent of X?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are jointly independent of $X$ such that $P(A,B|X)=P(A,B)$.
Can it be shown that $A$ and $B^c$ are jointly independent of $X$, i.e., that
 $P(A,B^c|X)=P(A,B^c)$?

Intuition suggests this is true, following from the fact that if $B$ and $X$ are independent, then so are $B^c$ and $X$ (e.g., as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192151/prove-complements-of-independent-events-are-independent)). However, I am struggling to prove it with math, and I wondered if you might offer help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the notation, then I believe that the hypothesis is false.  I am assuming that $P(A,B)$ is the probability that both event $A$ and event $B$ are true and that $P(A, B|X)= P(A,B,X)/P(X)$.

Let $Y$ be a randomly rolled 6 sided die.  Let $A$ be the event that $Y$ is a 1,2, or 3.  Let $X$ be the event that $Y$ is not 1.  And, let the $B$ event be always false.  Then

$$P(A,B|X) = 0 = P(A,B),$$
$$P(A, B^C)= P(A) = 1/2, \quad\mathrm{\ and}$$
$$P(A, B^C|X) = P(A|X) = 2/5.$$