# prove if $E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{n}$ are independent events then $p(\cup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i})=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}[1-p(E_{i})]$

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

prove if $E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{n}$ are independent events then:

$p(\cup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i})=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}[1-p(E_{i})]$

my try:
$$
p(\cup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i})=1-p((\cup_{i=1}^{n}E_{i})^{c})=1-p(\cap_{i=1}^{n}E_{i}^{c})
=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}p(E_{i}^{c})=1-\prod_{i=1}^{n}[1-p(E_{i})]
$$
$E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{n}$ are independent,

so i guess $E_{1}^c,E_{2}^c,...,E_{n}^c$ are also independent

(I need to prove it but got little confused with all the Inclusion-Exclusion principle)

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192151/prove-complements-of-independent-events-are-independent

Comment: Thanks but I have to prove it with Inclusion-Exclusion principle

Comment: @DanielG Your proof using DeMorgan's is fine as is.